# Change marker image on Cluster ItemClick in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

How to Change marker icon on Cluster item click in android?

I need to change clicked cluster item icon and remaining icon will same another icon, if i clicked another cluster item clicked cluster icon will change and previously clicked cluster item icon and remaining un-clicked cluster items icon will same. How to do that in android google map if any one know this answer please help me to do that and thanks in advance!!

Comment: Would using a [Custom clustered marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#custom) help with this scenario? You can test out if you can still change the `ClusterManager`'s icon once you clicked.

Comment: Is this issue resolved?